# Integral of fractional expression $\int^3_0 \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}$

Tags: integration

I want to solve this integral and think about call $\sqrt{x+1} = t \rightarrow t^2 = x+1$
$$\int^3_0 \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{x+1}}$$
Now the integral is : $$\int^3_0 \frac{2tdt}{1+t}$$ now I need your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Substitute $1+t^2=u$

Comment: thanks so its double substitution.

Comment: upper limit will be 2 in last line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substitution is a good idea. The details are not quite right. We get $dx=2t\,dt$, and therefore our definite integral is equal to
$$\int_{t=1}^2 \frac{2t}{1+t}\,dt.$$
Now can you take over? It may be useful to note that $\frac{2t}{1+t}=2-\frac{2}{1+t}$.

Comment: what about $t^2$?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\int^2_0 \frac{2t\, dt}{1+t} &= 2\int^2_0 \frac{1+t-1}{1+t}\,dt \\
&= 2\int^2_0 \left( \frac{1+t}{1+t}-\frac{1}{1+t}\right)\,dt \\
&= 2\int^2_0\left( 1-\frac{1}{1+t}\right)\,dt \\
&= 2[ t-\log({1+t})]_0^2 \\
&= 2[ 2-\log 3] \\
\end{align}$$